# Mongo: network error while attempting to run command 'whatsmyuri' on host

Tags: mongodb, port, remote-access

I have been trying to access my mongo instance from another machine, but I get this error. I could not find many references to this `whatsmyuri` error. This is what I get from the external machine:

```
$ mongo <IP_ADDRESS>:27017/youtube_advertising -u user -p password

MongoDB shell version: 3.2.0
connecting to: <IP_ADDRESS>:27017/youtube_advertising
2016-02-19T17:10:02.923+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: network error while attempting to run command 'whatsmyuri' on host '<IP_ADDRESS>:27017'  :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:226:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

I have already changed the `/etc/mongod.conf` file, opened connections through port `27017` (with `iptables`) and restarted mongo. I am able to connect via `ssh` to that machine.

Searching about this `whatsmyuri`, I ran this command on mongo:

```
> db.runCommand( { whatsmyuri: 1 } )
{ "you" : "127.0.0.1:36990", "ok" : 1 }
```

I do not know if that `36990` port is right or wrong. Just in case I opened connections from there too, but still nothing.

Any ideas?

#### UPDATE

Checking the `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`, this is what I get when I try to connect from remote:

```
2016-02-19T10:41:07.292-0600 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from <EXT_IP_ADDRESS>:51800 #2 (1 connection now open)
2016-02-19T10:41:07.310-0600 I QUERY    [conn2]     operation isn't supported: 2010
2016-02-19T10:41:07.310-0600 I -        [conn2] Assertion: 16141:cannot translate opcode 2010
```

Comment: Anything interesting in the log?

Comment: I was just updating it :)

Answer (score 16):

Check your versions. That may help.

I was having the same problem. In my case, the server was version 3.2.0-rc2, while mongo shell version was 3.2.1.

Upgrading the server to 3.2.1 fixed the problem.

Comment: I think my problem was also different version numbers. They just weren't 3.2.0 and 3.2.1.

Answer (score 5):

This issue bit me when I was running two versions (3.4 and 4.2) of MongoDB on the same Windows 10 machine.  I ran v3.4 mongod with no problems mentioned in the console output, but then running the v3.4 mongo shell produced the above error.  Checking the Task Manager, it turned out there was a MongoDB process (I'm not sure, but I think it was for v4.2) running.  After ending that process through the Task Manager, the v3.4 mongo shell ran fine with no error.

Answer (score 3):

Using mongodb-community-shell

In MacOs `brew install mongodb/brew/mongodb-community-shell`

It will ask you to overwrite link with mongo command.

`brew link --overwrite mongodb-community-shell`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The issue arises when the mongo client's and server's version mismatch. 
Uninstall MongoDB from the client and for installation follow the detailed instruction provided over here.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

The key step which needs to be done with the attention is

> **sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=4.2.7 mongodb-org-server=4.2.7 mongodb-org-shell=4.2.7 mongodb-org-mongos=4.2.7
>   mongodb-org-tools=4.2.7**

Note: In my case, the mongo version of server was 4.2.7
Another thing that one can do is uninstall MongoDB from both the systems taking necessary backups and install it again.