# Connect to AWS over SSH portforward

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, openssh

I'd like to connect to my AWS instance and connect to my MongoDB database over localhost. <s>The SSH tunnel seems to work</s>, but when I try to connect with `mongo` I get a connection failed error.

**SSH tunnel command:**

```
ssh -i <path to key> -N -L 27017:++++++++++.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:27017 ++++++@++++++++++.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

**Mongo client:**

*mongo -u +++++++ -p ++++++++++ mongodb://localhost:27017/+++++*

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.7
connecting to: mongodb://localhost:27017/++++++
2018-01-22T15:32:07.125+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host 'localhost:27017'  :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

*On the tunnel side I then get:*

```
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

I have tried the mongo command directly on the server then there it works fine.

On my Robo T3 client there is an option to connect over SSH and there the connection works just fine.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

When I start the mongo client, no new lines are added to mongdb log file. This indicates that the tunnel is not doing it's job...

Answer (score 1):

According to [this documentation](https://www.aptible.com/documentation/enclave/troubleshooting/mongodb-error.html), this error happens when you try to connect to a MongoDB server **without ssl**.

The solution then would be to connect using SSL, which can be done by adding `--ssl` to your connection query (so that it looks like this: `mongo --ssl -u +++++++ -p ++++++++++ mongodb://localhost:27017/+++++`).

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: There are two other things you can try:
- [Try what is mentioned in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35509937/mongo-network-error-while-attempting-to-run-command-whatsmyuri-on-host), updating the server or shell version
- [Try replacing localhost with the local ip](https://lellansin.wordpress.com/2016/05/16/error-network-error-while-attempting-to-run-command-ismaster-on-host/), then binding it.

Comment: It shouldn't matter because the `Robo T3` client is able the connect over a SSH tunnel. So the server side should be fine.

Comment: While that would mean the update solution doesn't apply to your case, it must be doing differently to a direct connection. Can you check what's in the logs at `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`?

Comment: I updated my question. No new lines are added, so the tunnel is not working.

Comment: What's the output when you try connecting via `ssh` with the verbose flag (-v)?